# Stable distribution law related to the Dickman function

Tags: probability, number-theory, ordinary-differential-equations, statistics

It is known that if $U$ is a random variable with uniform distribution on the interval $(0,1]$, then the random variable defined as
$$
X\stackrel{d}{=} U^{1/\alpha}(1+X)
$$
where $\alpha>0$ possesses the Dickman distribution conventionally denoted as $\rho(x)$. The latter arises in Number Theory and is known there as the [Dickman function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickman_function).

The above distribution equation can be arrived at as the limit of the difference equation:
$$
X_k=U_k^{1/\alpha}(1+X_{k-1}),\; k\ge1,
$$
where $X_0=0$ and $U_k$'s are iid $(0,1]$-uniform and independent of $X_{k-1}$.
Then as $k\to\infty$ the recurrence yields the distribution equation above.

I am interested in the limiting (as $k\to\infty$) distribution of the following process:
$$
Z_k=V_k(1+Z_{k-1}),
$$
where
$$
V_k
=
\frac{1}{1+\theta} e^{\theta Y_k},\;\theta>0,
$$
and $Y_k$ are iid exponential with mean 1. It can be seen that the support of $V_k$ is $[1/(1+\theta),\infty)$ and that
$$
\Pr(V_k\ge t)=\Pr\left(Y_k\le \frac{1}{\theta}\log[t(1+\theta)]\right)=1-\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{\theta}\log[t(1+\theta)]\right\}=1-[t(1+\theta)]^{-1/\theta},
$$
so that the pdf of each $V_k$ is
$$
f_V(t)=\frac{1+\theta}{\theta} [t(1+\theta)]^{-(1+\theta)/\theta},\;t\ge1/(1+\theta).
$$

This is quite similar to the Dickman setup above and I suspect that the limiting distribution of $Z_k$ as $k\to\infty$ can be expressed via the Dickman function, but I fail to see what sort of variable-transformation applied to $Z_k$ would do the trick.